# Induction proof: if $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f:I_n\to B$, and $f$ is onto, then $B$ is finite and $|B|\le n$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

> Prove that if $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f:I_n\to B$, and $f$ is onto, then $B$ is finite and $|B|\le n$.

Attempt at a proof:

We use induction

Base case: When $n=0, I_0=\varnothing$ and since $f$ is onto $B=\varnothing$.

Inductive step:

Suppose $n\in\mathbb{N}$, Now suppose $g:I_{n+1}\to B$ is onto, then there is a $b\in I_{n+1}$ that fails to be in $I_{n}$, so it must be the case that $g(b)=g(a)$ such that $b\neq a$ for arbitrary $a\in I_{n+1}$ since $g$ is onto,  hence $g$ fails to be one-to-one. We construct a set $I_{n}'=I_{n+1}\setminus\{b\}$ and show that $f:I_{n}'\to B$ is one-to-one and onto.

Is my approach correct?  I'm particularly worried about where to include the induction hypothesis since this is after all a proof by induction. My goal is to prove that $f$ is one-to-one, forget the Cantor-Bernstein-Schroder theorem for now.

Comment: What is $\;I_n\;$, what is $\;B\;$... **what** is the question??

Comment: From the book i'm reading if $A$ is a finite set is then there is an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $I_{n}$~$A$ where ~ denotes equivalence of sets. $B$ is just an ordinary set.

Comment: So, in fact, it seems you want to ask: "prove that if there exists a surjective function $\;f:K\to B\;$ , with $\;K\;$ a *finite* set, then $\;B\;$ is a finite set, too" . Assuming I guessed correctly, I can't understand why you wrote what you wrote in such a cumbersome way.

Comment: That's what's in the book.

Comment: that's a rather poor excuse at any level above junior high school. One **first** has to understand the question and then ask about it.

Comment: I do understand that's why i attempted it and inquired on the correctness of my attempt

Comment: No @pkjag : you **have** to understand what's being asked, including the symbols. If you have any doubt about these then you have first to find out what these mean.

Comment: Another question: do you *have* to use induction or it is optional?

Comment: Its optional but i can't use the Cantor-Bernstein-Schroder theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, $I_n$ stands for a canonical $n$-element set, say $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$.

I can't really understand your try for the induction step, however it *tastes* something like that...

Let $f:I_{n+1}\to B$ surjective, and consider its restriction to $I_n$, $\ f':=f|_{I_n}$. If it is still surjective, we are ready by induction hypothesis $|B|\le n<n+1$.

We are left with the case when $f(n+1)\in B$ differs from all $f(k),\ k\le n$. *Now* take $B':=B\setminus\{f(n+1)\}$ and apply the induction hypothesis to $f':I_n\to B'$. So that $|B'|\le n$ and $B=B'\cup\{f(n+1)\}$.

Comment: Do i have to use the restricted function $f'$?? Can't i just use $f$ with $I_{n+1}\setminus\{b\}$ as the domain??

Answer (score 1):

Without induction: let $\;f:K\to B\;$ be a surjective sets map . Now, $\;\forall\,b\in B\;$ we choose one unique

$$k_b\in K\;\;s.t.\;\;f(k_b)=b$$

We're simply choosing an element in each fiber of each element in $\;B\;$ . One can use AC if wanted as we don't know a priori what the cardinality of $\;B\;$ is, though I think this can be avoided as it looks to me as overkill...anyway, now define

$$K':=\{k_b\in K\;;\;b\in B\}\;,\;\;g:B\to K'\;,\;\;g(b):=k_b$$

Then, clearly $\;g\;$ is injective and thus $\;|B|\le |K'|\le |K|<\infty\;$  , since $\;K'\subset K\;$

Comment: So given a function that is onto, this method can be used generally to show that another function related to the first is one-to-one??

Comment: It may depend on the sets **and** on the assumptions you can make. For example, for general sets "choosing" as I did above can be hard, or even impossible, if you can't use AC (=Axiom of Choice)